# How to reset Google Captcha Response in Server Side Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

How to clear or reset the response of Google Recapthca after form post is done.

**Client side**

```
@{
    var captchaSiteKey = Captcha_SiteKey;
 }


<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("controller","action", FormMethod.Post))
{
       <div>

        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="@captchaSiteKey"></div><br /><br />

        <div class="form-submit-border">
            <input id="idvalue" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

Server side

below line to get captcha response in server side

```
  var captchaResponse = HttpContext.Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"];
```

after validation done. how to reset or clear the recaptcha response?

Comment: What does your server side code resemble? Are you creating an HTTP client to make a call to Google?  I would suggest reviewing the Google reCAPTCHA documentation (see link),  you will still have to post that reCAPTCHA response to the back-end to then call out to Google and verify that the response is in fact valid. If it is successful, then you can proceed with your processing, otherwise return invalidating the reCAPTCHA.

[https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display][1]

Comment: I am using Http post method in html.beginform at time of page refresh the form value submit once again  so its shows captcha validation error in the page.